# Django taggit url pattern not working in Production

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I was successfully using Django-taggit in development environment but when I have pushed the app to server it has started getting error in url for taggit.

```
Reverse for 'tagged' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['ads\\/tag\\/(?P<slug>[^/]+)$']
```

My url:

```
path('ads/tag/<slug>', views.filtered_ads, name="tagged")
```

My href:

```
 {% for tag in data.tags.all %}
     <a href="{% url 'app:tagged' tag.slug %}" class="mr-1 badge badge-info">{{ tag.name }}</a>
 {% endfor %}
```

Any thoughts, why is it happening as I am unable to find the problem?